# Execution analyze of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.0:analyze-only failed: This feature requires ASM7

Tags: maven

I am using `open jdk-11`. When I run maven, I am getting below error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.0:analyze-only (analyze) on project mobilefabric-install-common: Execution analyze of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.0:analyze-only failed: This feature requires ASM7 -> [Help 1]


org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.0:analyze-only (analyze) on project mobilefabric-install-common: Execution analyze of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.0:analyze-only failed: This feature requires ASM7
```

Maven versions : 3.6.1

`pom.xml`:

```
<artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.1.1</version>
<dependencies> 
  <dependency> 
   <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId> 
   <artifactId>asm</artifactId> 
   <version>7.2-beta</version> 
  </dependency> 
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Please use the most recent version of maven-dependency-plugin which is 3.1.1 which runs on JDK 11..

Comment: I used maven-dependency-plugin 3.1.1, still facing same issue

Comment: Please show the full pom file cause I don't understand cause I'm working a JDK 11 project without any issue...

Answer (score 2):

This configuration works for me on Java 11:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-dependency-analyzer</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Origin: [Rune Flobakk's comment](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-613?focusedCommentId=16750925&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16750925) on MDEP-613